# How can I add a usb device to a domain xml from an image file?

Tags: usb, libvirt, fat32

I don't (repeat DONT) want to passthrough a physical usb device. I'm making a usb img file like so:

```
dd if=/dev/null bs=1K of=/tmp/test_usb.img seek=2040
mkfs.vfat /tmp/test_usb.img
```

I am then attempting to create the domain with the following xml:

```xml
<disk type="file" device="disk">
    <driver name="qemu" type="raw/>
    <source file="/tmp/test_usb.img"/>
    <target dev="sda" bus="usb"/>
</disk>
```

Inside the windows guest, it shows up as a QEMU USB HARDDISK (or similar name), but I cannot access it. Now, I'm not intending for this to show up as a usb-harddrive. I want it to be a plain-old FAT32 USB.

How do I do this?

EDIT (added picture)

[image: Properties of QEMU USB HARDDISK]

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to create drive like:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero bs=1K of=/tmp/test_usb.img bs=100M count=1
  ```

  Copy **/dev/zero**, not **/dev/null**
- Second, check your domain for presence of usb controllers initialization options:

  ```
  <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x7'/>
  </controller>
  <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
  <master startport='0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
  </controller>
  <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
  <master startport='2'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x1'/>
  </controller>
  <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
  <master startport='4'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x2'/>
  </controller>
  ```
- Thrid, you need to initialize new disks in windows guest:

  Steps from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782513%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

  1. Open Computer Management (Local).
  2. In the console tree, click **Computer Management (Local)**, click **Storage**, and then click **Disk Management**.
  3. Right-click the disk you want to initialize, and then click **Initialize Disk**.
  4. In the **Initialize** Disk dialog box, select the disk(s) to initialize.

  *An alternative way, you can make partition table on your hard disk at once after `dd`'ing. use `parted` or `cfdisk` utils for it.*